# Ubuntu 20.04, libimobiledevice issue | cp: cannot open 'filename' for reading: Input/output error

Tags: libimobiledevice

When I connect my iPhone to my PC via USB, there are two mount points automatically created, such as:

1. /run/user/1000/gvfs/afc:host=00008101-001C6C480E68001E,port=3
2. /run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2:host=Apple_Inc._iPhone_00008101001C6C480E68001E

The second mount point listed contains photos from my Photos app that live naively on my iPhone, and I am able to copy those files from my iPhone to my PC without issue.

The first mount point listed contains files stored on my device by other apps I have installed. However, whenever I attempt to copy any of the files from any of those app directories to my PC, I get the following error:

cp: cannot open '*filename*' for reading: Input/output error

After an attempt to copy or read the file, if then I attempt to list the files in that directory, I get the following error:

ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
total 0

...and no files are listed.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it, or can anyone advise which logs I could provide to help triage the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to access from `/run/user/1000/gvfs/afc:host=00008101-001C6C480E68001E` (without the port). I/O errors are often due to libimobiledevice unable to deal with files having more than 1 hard link.

Comment: I'm getting a "bash: cd: /run/user/1000/gvfs/afc:host=00008101-001C6C480E68001E: No such file or directory" when I try to navigate to the directory without the port